# How to create textbox onchange of checkbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have three check-boxes with one label. three checkboxes are like this

```html
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Grains</label>               
<div class="col-md-10 columns">                    
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Apple"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Apple" value="Apple">Jawora</label>             
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Orange"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Orange" value="Orange">Bajara</label>      
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Bananas"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_other" value="other">other</label> 
</div>
```

When I select other or last checkbox then I want generate one textbox for filling other product name.

Comment: There's a good chance that you'll get more help if you take a stab at the javascript yourself first. I'll help this afternoon if nobody has helped at that point, but I have to go do some stuff this morning. In the mean time, read up on manipulating DOM objects through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Dont generate it simply show it when the checkbox is checked

```js
$('input[name="Checkboxes"]').click(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){ 
  $('.hidden').show();
  }
else{
  $('.hidden').hide();
  }
  
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Grains</label>               
    <div class="col-md-10 columns">                    
     <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Apple"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Apple" value="Apple">Jawora</label>             
     <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Orange"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Orange" value="Orange">Bajara</label>      
     <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Bananas"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_other" value="other">other</label> 
                  <div class="hidden">Hidden input<input type="checkbox"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
$('#Checkboxes_other').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // Check if an input already exists
    if (!($(this).parent().find('#custom_type').length != 0)) {
      // Append an input
      $(this).parent().append('<input id="custom_type" type="text" placeholder="Type your value here">');
    }
  } else {
      // Remove the input if 'other' got unchecked
      $(this).parent().find('#custom_type').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Grains</label>
<div class="col-md-10 columns">
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Apple">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Apple" value="Apple">Jawora</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Orange">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Orange" value="Orange">Bajara</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Bananas">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_other" value="other">other</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".show").on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var label = $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']");

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //show textbox
        console.log(id);
       alert(label.text());
    } else {
        //hide textbox
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brhgo1aq/1/)

Use on change of the checkbox event

Answer (score 0):

Add a text box:

```
<label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Checkboxes">Grains</label>               
<div class="col-md-10 columns">                    
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Apple"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Apple" value="Apple">Jawora</label>             
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Orange"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_Orange" value="Orange">Bajara</label>      
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="Checkboxes_Bananas"><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxes" id="Checkboxes_other" value="other">other</label>
  <label class="text-box" for="other"><input type="text" id="txtOther" /></label>
</div>
```

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#Checkboxes_other").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $("#txtOther").show();
    } else {
       $("#txtOther").hide();
    }
 });
</script>
```